# Is there a difference in execution between vanilla js and google apps script? The same code renders errors in apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have written a bit of code to look up rates and calculate a price. I have written this in a standard IDE and it works just fine:

```js
let rangeAirlines = [
  ['ICN - BKK', 'Sun May 31 00: 00: 00 GMT + 07: 00 2020', 'KE(express)', 4.55, 3.7, 3.3, 3.25],
  ['ICN - BKK', 'Sun May 31 00: 00: 00 GMT + 07: 00 2020', 'OZ(express)', 4.4, 4.05, 4.0, 3.95],
  ['ICN - BKK', 'Sun May 31 00: 00: 00 GMT + 07: 00 2020', 'TG', 3.8, 3.35, 3.3, 3.25]
]

function convertRange (array) {
  
  const airlineObjects = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
    const [leg, date, airline, rate45, rate100, rate300, rate500] = array[i];

    airlineObjects.push({"airline": airline, "rate45Bp": [45, rate45], "rate100Bp": [100, rate100], "rate300Bp": [300, rate300], "rate500Bp": [500, rate500], "validity": new Date(date)});

  }
  return airlineObjects;
}

function addBreakpoints(airlineData) {
  const breakpoints = airlineData;

  for (let line of breakpoints) {
    line.rate45Bp.push(Math.round(line.rate100Bp[0] * line.rate100Bp[1] / line.rate45Bp[1]));
    line.rate100Bp.push(Math.round(line.rate300Bp[0] * line.rate300Bp[1] / line.rate100Bp[1]));
    line.rate300Bp.push(Math.round(line.rate500Bp[0] * line.rate500Bp[1] / line.rate300Bp[1]));
  }
  return breakpoints;
}

function findCarrierObject(bpData, carrier, today) {
  //check if today is smaller or equal than validity ? return color green : color red; // add method to set text color.
  let carrierObj = {};
  for (var line of bpData) {
    if (line.airline === carrier) {
      return carrierObj = line;
    };
  }
}

function getRates(obj) {
  let rateLines = [];

  for (let line in obj) {
    Array.isArray(obj[line]) ? rateLines.push(obj[line]) : "error";
  }
  return rateLines;
};

function calcPriceAir(arr, weight) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const [weightBreak, rate, breakpoint] = arr[i];
    if (weight <= weightBreak) {
      return weightBreak * rate;
    }
    if (weight <= breakpoint && breakpoint !== undefined) {
      return weight * rate;
    }
  }

  const lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
  return weight * lastItem[1];
}

function calcPriceAirfreight(range, airline, weight) {
  const data = convertRange (range);
  
  const breakpointsObject = addBreakpoints(data);
  
  const carrierObj = findCarrierObject(breakpointsObject, airline);
  
  const rates = getRates(carrierObj);
  
  return calcPriceAir(rates, weight);
}

const price = calcPriceAirfreight(rangeAirlines, "OZ(express)", 540);
console.log(price);
```

It is meant to be used in a spreadsheet, that's where it gets stuck in the helper function calcPriceAir(). The error message reads:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined (line 53, file "Code")

It makes no sense to me.

**Are there any experienced apps script developers out there that can spot where I am going wrong?**

*TLDR:*

- function convertRange(array) => this function converts the range in sheets into an object.
- function addBreakpoints(airlineData) => this function adds breakpoints used in the airline business to determine which rate to use.
- function findCarrierObject(bpData, carrier, today) => this function finds the rate set that is valid and needs to be used.
- function getRates(obj) => this function strips the object to its bare bones. This step is maybe not necessary, but I am new at this and made it easier for me to process the rates further.
- function calcPriceAir(arr, weight) => this function calculates the price.
- Finally, the custom function I will show in the spreadsheet. Here you add an airline and your weight. It will return the price. All the functions above will be made hidden.

```js
function convertRange(array) {
  const airlineObjects = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const [leg, date, airline, rate45, rate100, rate300, rate500] = array[i];
    airlineObjects.push({"airline": airline, "rate45Bp": [45, rate45], "rate100Bp": [100, rate100], "rate300Bp": [300, rate300], "rate500Bp": [500, rate500], "validity": new Date(date)});
  }
  return airlineObjects;
}

function addBreakpoints(airlineData) {
  const breakpoints = airlineData;

  for (let line of breakpoints) {
    line.rate45Bp.push(Math.round(line.rate100Bp[0] * line.rate100Bp[1] / line.rate45Bp[1]));
    line.rate100Bp.push(Math.round(line.rate300Bp[0] * line.rate300Bp[1] / line.rate100Bp[1]));
    line.rate300Bp.push(Math.round(line.rate500Bp[0] * line.rate500Bp[1] / line.rate300Bp[1]));
  }
  return breakpoints;
}

function findCarrierObject(bpData, carrier, today) {
  //check if today is smaller or equal than validity ? return color green : color red; // add method to set text color.
  let carrierObj = {};
  for (var line of bpData) {
    if (line.airline === carrier) {
      return carrierObj = line;
    };
  }
}

function getRates(obj) {
  let rateLines = [];

  for (let line in obj) {
    Array.isArray(obj[line]) ? rateLines.push(obj[line]) : "error";
  }
  return rateLines;
};

function calcPriceAir(arr, weight) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const [weightBreak, rate, breakpoint] = arr[i];
    if (weight <= weightBreak) {
      return weightBreak * rate;
    }
    if (weight <= breakpoint && breakpoint !== undefined) {
      return weight * rate;
    }
  }

  const lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
  return weight * lastItem[1];
  Logger.log(weight); Logger.log(arr[arr.length-1])
}

function calcPriceAirfreight(airline, weight) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const airfreightSheet = ss.getSheetByName("airfreight");
  const rangeAirlines = 
        airfreightSheet.getRange(3,1,airfreightSheet.getLastRow()-2,7).getValues();
  
  const data = convertRange (rangeAirlines);
  
  const breakpointsObject = addBreakpoints(data);
  
  const carrierObj = findCarrierObject(breakpointsObject, airline);
  
  const rates = getRates(carrierObj);
  
  return calcPriceAir(rates, weight);
}

const price = calcPriceAirfreight("OZ(express)", 540);
Logger.log(price);
```

Comment: Welll, how to put it... It's not the same code. And that is likely what causes the error. Since GAS-specific classes exist only in GAS environment, you must've used a different driver function. Are you **absolutely sure** that `calcPriceAirfreight` gets **the same arguments** in GAS and JS (just log and compare)? Also note that for vanilla.js you can (and should) create runnable snippets right in the body of the question

Comment: @OlegValter I am in the process of reviewing (not easy for a newbie like me :-)). As per your suggestion, I have added the original code as well.

Comment: I have executed each step and logged it. That worked all fine. I even got the right price returned. This is the test I ran:

Comment: ```javascript
function test () {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const airfreightSheet = ss.getSheetByName("airfreight");
  const rangeAirlines = airfreightSheet.getRange(3,1,airfreightSheet.getLastRow()-2,7).getValues();
  const data = convertRange (rangeAirlines);
  const breakpointsObject = addBreakpoints(data);
  const carrierObj = findCarrierObject(breakpointsObject, "TG");
  const rates = getRates(carrierObj);
  console.log(calcPriceAir(rates, 540));
}
```

Comment: I still haven't found why the code breaks when running the identical calcPriceAirfreight function. But getting closer ... thx.

Comment: @OlegValter I found the error using your suggestion. Posted it as the answer. But I do not understand why this works. Can you shed a light on that? --- just ran it again same problem. So it's not the answer. I will look at this some other day and delete my answer. You put me in the right direction though, thx.

Comment: Since the answer was deleted before I could comment: "Well, I agree, it would not change anything. Is this *really* the only change you made? I at least see two `Logger.log` calls removed (although they are unreachable, the fact of removal makes me doubt that the line affected was the only thing changed). Can you clarify if literally putting the line back changes the whole workflow?"

Comment: @OlegValter the solution is really silly. As a last resort, I had made two identical functions and compared them line by line.I realized that the arguments were not passed in when running the function in the google editor. When I called the function in my spreadsheet with two arguments,  the right answer was returned. =calcPriceAirfreight(cell ref to "airline", cell ref to "weight"); I won't make this mistake again. Have a great day!

Comment: Well, obviously they weren't :) You should read about [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function) since that is what you are using, they have a very restrictive context of execution. What you execute in code editor is run as normal JavaScript (with a flavour of Google APIs) server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function with arguments is just slightly different in Apps Script Editor compared to what you would do in an ordinary IDE. Simply `console.log(function(arg1, arg2))` does not work. It's quite obvious now but did not cross my mind for a while, waisting time looking for an error that was not there.

At the end of the day, all it took was to call the function in my spreadsheet with two arguments passed in (in my case two cell references). Although it may just me being inexperienced.

Comment: Re: console - no, unfortunately, you are not correct, it *does* work. But in server-side JS it just means something a bit different - instead of browser console (or "Logs" tab if you'd used `Logger.log()`) the logs are sent to Stackdriver console, and you can access them there (or in an "Executions" tab of the Apps Script Dashboard).

Comment: @OlegValter noted!